# insert data in MySQL from Url

Tags: php, json, xml

I have these 2 URLs

https://www.live-rates.com/rates?rate_format=xml

https://www.live-rates.com/rates?key=07b8395b08

and want to import it to mysql database in php code and update it each 10 min

I try use that code but not work

```
<?php
//
        $_user = '';
        $_password= '';
        $_db = 'test';
        $_host = 'localhost';
        $_port = 3306;
    $con = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_db) or die(mysql_error);

$content=file_get_contents("https://www.live-rates.com/rates?key=07b8395b08");
$data=json_decode($content);

     $id = $json->device->sn;
    foreach($json->data as $key => $data){
        if(empty($data) || !isset($data->{'$ts'})){
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($data->{'$msg'})){
            $msg = $data->{'$msg'};
            $time = $data->{'$ts'};

            $sql="INSERT into error_log ( currency , rate  , Bid , Ask , high  , low  , open  , close  , timestamp ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); ";
            $stmt = $con-> prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bind_param("iss", $id,$time, $msg);
            $stmt -> execute();
        }else{
            $time = (isset($data->{'$ts'}))? $data->{'$ts'}:'';
            $RH = (isset($data->RH))? $data->RH:'';
            $AT = (isset($data->AT))? $data->AT:'';
            $MINVi = (isset($data->MINVi))? $data->MINVi:'';

            //insert into mysql table
            $sql="INSERT into tx (currency , rate  , Bid , Ask , high  , low  , open  , close  , timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); ";
            $stmt = $con-> prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bind_param("issss", $id,$time,$RH,$AT,$MINVi);
            $stmt -> execute();
        }


    }
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

always show me this messages

```
Notice: Undefined variable: json in xxxxxx\add.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxx\add.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxx\add.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined variable: json in xxxxxxxxx\add.php on line 24

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxxx\add.php on line 24

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxxxxxxx\add.php on line 24
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi there, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then you will see that your question doesn't fit stackoverflows standards. you don't describe a specific problem but appear to ask for someone to code your problem for free.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sorry I forget to insert code within post

Comment: "_but not work_" What does that mean? Does it insert wrong data? No data at all? Getting a white page? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Not a `bind_param()` expert here, but there are 9 parameters to be bound in that one query but you bind only 3 `bind_param("iss", $id,$time, $msg);` with "strange" values

Comment: As for your error messages: `$id = $json->device->sn;` where did you define `$json`?

Comment: it's my 1 day in Json i try to define Json as  $content=file_get_contents("https://www.live-rates.com/rates?key=07b8395b08");
$data=json_decode($content);

Answer (score 0):

GET and POST depends on what you are passing
extract($_GET);
Use insert query with key and value

Comment: insert query with key and value but 
it's update values each 10 min